# High resolution laptop not displaying control boxes properly in QGIS (Windows 10)

Tags: qgis-plugins, resolution, display, windows-10

I have recently installed QGIS 2.18.2 to my new Asus Zenbook Windows 10 64 bit. My issue is that (see image) some of the plugins...the initial one - go to coordinates (essential) is not displaying correctly as my screen is very high DPI. I have found the settings to change icon/text size which has helped.

I would prefer not to have to reduce the resolution of my entire laptop - however don't mind so much if its only for QGIS.

I found this link online which seemed helpful - except the .exe that Windows points to didn't change anything when I created manifest file.

http://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/

I haven't tried hooking it up to a separate monitor yet as I am awaiting a cable arriving in the post. However I really need it to work on the standalone laptop for work in the field.

[image: QGIS res]